# Nested Quantifier placement confusion

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I'm working on a question right now that's asking me the difference between
"For every integer a, b, if for every integer x, ax+b is even ... " and
"For every integer a, b, x if ax+b is even ..."

I already proved the first statement as true but I'm struggling to find a concrete difference between the two statements. If anybody can sort of explain the difference for me, I'd greatly appreciate that.
Thanks!

Comment: Your sentences appear to be of the form:$$\begin{align}&\forall a~\forall b~((\forall x~\mathrm P(a,b,x))\to\mathrm Q(a,b))\tag 1\\[2ex]&\forall a~\forall b~\forall x~(\mathrm P(a,b,x)\to\mathrm Q(a,b))\tag 2\end{align}$$Is this so?

Comment: @GrahamKemp yep!

Comment: @GrahamKemp The second is more likely $\forall a\,\forall b\,\forall x\,(P(a, b, x) \rightarrow R(a, b, x))$, no? Otherwise, "who talks like that"? :)

Comment: @BrianO Graham's sentence (2) might mean "for each couple and dog, the couple is a pet owner if the couple owns the dog"...

Comment: Right, but it might also be, "for every integer a, b, x, if ax + b > 0 then a = 0 or x > -b/a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Graham's comment and filtering out the $a,b$:
$$\big(\forall x~\mathrm P(x)\big)\Rightarrow\mathrm Q\tag{1e}$$$$\forall x~\big(\mathrm P(x)\Rightarrow\mathrm Q\big)\tag{2e}$$

Sentence $(2\mathrm e)$ asserts that $\ldots,\big(P(-7)\Rightarrow Q\big),\ldots,\big(P(0)\Rightarrow Q\big),\ldots,\big(P(31)\Rightarrow Q\big),\ldots$ are all true ($x$ is varying over its entire domain); equivalently, that if *some* $P(x)$ is true, then $Q$ is true; i.e., $$\forall x~\big(\mathrm P(x)\Rightarrow\mathrm Q\big)\;\equiv\;\big(\exists x~\mathrm P(x)\big)\Rightarrow\mathrm Q.\tag{2e}$$

In comparison, sentence $(1\mathrm e)$ is a weaker assertion: it is applicable (usefully invoked) in fewer scenarios, since its hypothesis $\big(\forall x~\mathrm P(x)\big)$ is harder to satisfy than $(2\mathrm e)$'s hypothesis $\big(\exists x~\mathrm P(x)\big).$

For completeness: $$\big(\forall x~\mathrm P(x)\big)\Rightarrow\mathrm Q\;\equiv\;\exists x~\big(\mathrm P(x)\Rightarrow\mathrm Q\big).\tag{1e}$$

Comment: For completeness, you should state the assumption that $x$ is not free in $Q$, otherwise your $\equiv$ statements aren't valid. [Their numbers are off: you already used (2e) and (1e).] For the first of OP's sentences, your first (1e), that's probably true of her "...". However, for the second, "For every integer a, b, x if ax+b is even ...",  in most cases "..." probably **does** involve $x$.

Comment: @BrianO 1. My first sentence made clear that the Answer is premised on Graham's suggestion/clarification, which the OP verified to be consistent with her Question's intent. My (1edited) & (2edited) correspond to Graham's (1) & (2).   2. Using (1e) and (2e) twice was intentional, and meant to exhibit the Prenex forms. 3. "$P(x)$" and "$Q$" appearing in the same sentence suggests that $x$ is free in $P$ but not in $Q.$

Comment: Ah ok, I see why you repeated the numbers – a good reason, too. I commented to @GrahamKemp similarly. It's unusual for anyone to say or write, "for all a, b, x, if ax + b is even then a + b is even"  when they mean, for all a, b, "if there is an x such that if ax + b is even then a + b is even". I don't think it's nitpicky: in statements of the form "for all $a, b, x$, if $A$ then $B$", often both $A$ and $B$ involve $x$.